# Using egrep to find matches in a file while piping output from a cat command

Tags: linux, grep

I am using cat to output 6 lines of text from a text file called wordlist.txt. I am piping it to egrep and want to find matches in a second file called 8compdic.txt

command I am using is given below:

```
cat wordlist.txt | egrep - 8compdic.txt | less
```

Am getting output which has all the lines in *compdic.txt

Answer (score 2):

Use `-f wordlist.txt` with `grep` to tell it to read the patterns from your file. Use `-F` to tell it that the patterns are fixed strings rather than regular expressions. And use `grep -E` rather than `egrep` (for portability):

```
$ grep -E -F -f wordlist.txt 8compdic.txt | less
```

If you want to restrict the matches to full lines, add `-x` to the `grep` command. Without `-x`, the word `make` in `wordlist.txt` would match words like `makes`, `makeshiftiness` and `wafermaker` in the file you're grepping.

Comment: The solutions are not working for me. I would like to actually pipe the output to grep and the output lines need to be matched from 8compdic.txt. Thanks.

Comment: Also would empty lines create a problem?

Comment: @MohanChunkath Then use `-f /dev/stdin` with `grep`. If you use `-x`, then empty lines will match empty lines. Without `-x`, empty lines will match all lines.